# SWT Virtual Keyboard implementation

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm writing an application using SWT and JFace and it will be used on a machine without a physical keyboard. Do you know if there is something already done for that purpose?
I found a project that uses Swing: https://github.com/oxus20/Java-VirtualKeyboard.

I was wondering if I have to convert it to SWT by myself or there are already projects like that for SWT.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a ready to use library that implements a virtual keyboard in SWT.

My (untested) approach would be to use Display::post() with SWT.KeyDown and SWT.KeyUp events to simulate keystrokes.

Display::post() has subtle differences on different platforms. This forum post may help to work around some of them: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1072641/

Comment: Thank you 4 your reply Rudiger, I have just converted the swing version I have found, in SWT. A limited version of it: the machine on which the app is going to run has a keyboard with just numbers and  arrow keys. But in some part of the app I need to do a search. it's not complete at the moment but I'm happy with it...For the keystrokes I have used a Robot and on windows it seems to work. I need to verify if it will work on Mac as well...

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You may want to self-answer your question with the relevant code snippets so that others can benefit from your findings as well.

Comment: I'm busy at the moment as soon as possible I will post a comment with my solution